# problem Flag_secure not work in delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

i am a create project in delphi 10.2.3 and work fine FLAG_SECURE code in firemonky android app . but update delphi to 10.3 just code not work and not black screen in record screen. i am use to code but not work
please help.

```
uses
  ...,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Helpers.Android;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SharedActivity.getWindow.setFlags(TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_SECURE, TJWindowManager_LayoutParams.JavaClass.FLAG_SECURE);
end;
```

```
uses
 Androidapi.NativeActivity;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
 AWINDOW_FLAG_SECURE = $00002000;
begin
  ANativeActivity_setWindowFlags(PANativeActivity(System.DelphiActivity), AWINDOW_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
end;
```

this two code work fine in delphi 10.2.3 but not work in delphi 10.3.

Comment: HOW does the code not work exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  This code will black screen when the user wants to shoot or record the screen. work fine in delphi 10.2.3 but not work in delphi 10.3. in the delphi 10.3 when run app in phone but not black screen and esay record screen.